# Bioconda packages r-wgcna and bioconductor-go.db not showing up in R

Tags: python, r, conda, bioconductor

I used `conda` to install R and `WGCNA` from the `bioconda` channel, seemingly successfully:

```
$ conda list | grep bioconda
bioconductor-annotationdbi 1.44.0                   r351_0    bioconda
bioconductor-biobase      2.42.0           r351h1de35cc_1    bioconda
bioconductor-biocgenerics 0.28.0                   r351_1    bioconda
bioconductor-go.db        3.7.0                    r351_0    bioconda
bioconductor-impute       1.56.0           r351ha44fe06_0    bioconda
bioconductor-iranges      2.16.0           r351h1de35cc_0    bioconda
bioconductor-preprocesscore 1.44.0           r351h470a237_0    bioconda
bioconductor-s4vectors    0.20.1           r351h470a237_0    bioconda
r-wgcna                   1.66             r351h466af19_1    bioconda
```

However `WGCNA` and `GO.db` don't show up in R using `installed.packages()`, though all the other packages listed above do.